# Batch load multiple custom commands from file

Tags: batch-file, load, command

I have made search on Google and Stack Overflow for quite a bit, but I couldn't find any help and solutions.

I have a file named `settings.ini` and I want to let user add custom commands to it.

The command has to be like this: `.CustomCommand=ExecuteCommand`

```
for /f "delims=.= tokens=2" %%a in ('more settings.ini ^| findstr "="') do (set customcommand=%%a)`
```

It doesn't work wery well and people told me to play around with `for` command, but no success.

Can you solve it for me?

Comment: please show us a part of your "settings.ini". The solution stronlgy depends on how it looks like.

Comment: #--- Custom commands  
#NOTE: Every custom command must start with the . symbol  
.a=autoclean -debug  
.thiscommandisreallyepic=run dfex.exe -debug

Comment: I can't create a newline on the comment so the comment is a mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather you need this:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=.=" %%a in ('more settings.ini ^| findstr "="') do (set %%~a=%%~b)
```

and you can call your command enclosed with `%`

or you can use :

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=.=" %%a in ('more settings.ini ^| findstr "="') do (echo %%~b>%%~a.bat)
```

For direct call (even you can set the produced `bat` in the `%PATH%`)

`eol=;` is for skipping lines that start with `;` - the standard comments for ini files.